# Restore Firefox group tabs and previously opened tabs

Tags: 11.04, firefox

Yesterday while I closed Firefox (latest 10.1), I noticed Firefox window left behind, which was just some popup browser window from Google when I tested a page design (how would it look on a mobile phone). So I closed that window afterwards also.

Today I open Firefox and instead expected leftover tabs, I see only this tiny Firefox window (from phone design test), without tabs. Even more importantly I had tab groups which also disappeared, just because I forgot that browser popup window was left behind before closing Firefox.

Can I restore group tabs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can!

<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> will restore closed windows, even between sessions.

I'm constantly accidentally firing this off when I switch to Chromium for private tab-testing (Chromium uses this shortcut to start a private-mode window) and old Firefox windows pop up because Firefox still has focus.

Comment: Thanks <3 You saved my day. I was hopelessly digging in Firefox profile folder :D

Comment: Lol, good find.